# Azure VNet Peering with multiple subscription in mutiple AD. Possible?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Me and my colleague have Azure accounts (with BizSpark plan). We both created VNets and some VMs in each. Now, he want to access some VMs that I have created so we tried to setup VNet peering between these accounts. Is it possible to do that?

PS: we tried for the VNet peering option as the VPN is costly.

More Info :

- There is no overlapping IP range.
- All the VMs are in the same region(South Central US).
- Have different Tenant IDs for the subscription
  [image: Tenant Ids]

PPS: More infö while following  [the tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnetpeering-arm-ps/)

I have Two subscription:

**Sub1 :**
SubscriptionName : Visual Studio Enterprise: BizSpark
SubscriptionId   : 79409421-0edc-40c5-a55b-4ef3ccfb0d53
TenantId         : b726dcac-a1f2-420b-8713-cbee132aa6cc
User Login ID    : aaaa@example.com
VNet Name        : vnet1
Resource Group   : newRG

**Sub2:**

SubscriptionName : Visual Studio Enterprise: BizSpark
SubscriptionId   : 3a97ecb8-5b69-4f7b-a46b-a678eb05ae00
TenantId         : 88cc20a7-90cf-4854-9201-6f1424ebf7fa
User Login ID    : bbbb@example.com
VNet Name        : vnet2
Resource Group   : newRG

I opened two Powershell windows and run commands as follows

### **Window1 (for Sub 1):**

```
Login-AzureRmAccount ( logged in with aaaa@example.com )  
 Get-AzureRmSubscription  
 Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "79409421-0edc-40c5-a55b-4ef3ccfb0d53"  

 New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "bbbb@example.com" -RoleDefinitionName "Network Contributor" -Scope /subscriptions/79409421-0edc-40c5-a55b-4ef3ccfb0d53/resourceGroups/newRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks/vnet2
```

when I run the above command, the error I got is

```
 New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The provided information does not map to an AD object id.
 At line:1 char:1
 + New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "bbbb@example.com" -RoleDefi ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleAssignment], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

then when I run command

```
 $vnet1 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName newRG -Name vnet1

 Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkPeering -name LinkTovnet2 -VirtualNetwork $vnet1 -RemoteVirtualNetworkId "/subscriptions/3a97ecb8-5b69-4f7b-a46b-a678eb05ae00/resourceGroups/newRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet2" -BlockVirtualNetworkAccess
```

the error is

```
 Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkPeering : The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action' on scope     '/subscriptions/79409421-0edc-40c5-a55b-4ef3ccfb0d53/resourceGroups/newRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/virtualNetworkPeerings/LinkTovnet2', however the linked subscription '3a97ecb8-5b69-4f7b-a46b-a678eb05ae00'is not in current tenant 'b726dcac-a1f2-420b-8713-cbee132aa6cc'.
 StatusCode: 403
 ReasonPhrase: Forbidden
 OperationID : 'a2e1807b-df0d-4ef5-b832-a166a781bfbe'
 At line:1 char:1
 + Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkPeering -name LinkTovnet2 -VirtualNet ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkPeering], NetworkCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.AddAzureVirtualNetworkPeeringCommand
```

### Window2 (for Sub 2):

```
 Login-AzureRmAccount( logged in with bbbb@example.com )
 Get-AzureRmSubscription
 Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "79409421-0edc-40c5-a55b-4ef3ccfb0d53"

 New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "aaaa@example.com" - RoleDefinitionName "Network Contributor" -Scope /subscriptions/3a97ecb8-5b69-4f7b-a46b-a678eb05ae00/resourceGroups/newRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/VirtualNetworks/vnet1
```

when I run the above command, getting the same error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Peering can be established between virtual networks in two different subscriptions as long a privileged user of both subscriptions authorizes the peering and the subscriptions are associated to the same Active Directory tenant. "

There are some other caveats on the page I've linked to below, eg. you cant have overlapping ip address ranges.

See [Azure vnet peering](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-network-peering-overview/)

Comment: I followed this tutorial and ended up in a permission issue. I think both subscriptions are having different tenant IDs. is there some way to make these two subscription to same tenant. @russell-young, updated the question.

Comment: So did you add the same directory tenant to both subscriptions?  Once you've done that, when you use select-azurermsubscription use the -tenantid parameter as well to choose the right tenant

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Go to the classic portal, Active Directory, click add, then choose "existing directory", and follow the prompts, you will need to have an ID that's a global admin of the directory you want to add.